# CMD echo working with PLINK>exe

Tags: cmd.exe, echo, plink

good day, I tried to use the format below for my plink and when I went to login with the username I changed the password on it didn't accept the new password.  so my question is, when using "(echo.password1 & echo.password1)" what is it sending?  Is it sending "password1" as the new password or is it "password1 "?

Below is the block code i used, changing my username and password

'''

```
(echo.mypassword & echo.password1 & echo.password1) | plink -ssh -batch myusername@192.168.100.250 -pw mypassword "sudo passwd admin"
```

'''

here is the output. NOTE on the user usroob, i have sudo setup so I don't need to put in my password.

```
C:\Users\Thomas Bonar>(echo.password1 & echo.password1) | plink -ssh -batch usroob@192.168.100.250 -pw mypassword "sudo passwd admin"
New password: Retype new password: passwd: password updated successfully 
C:\Users\Thomas Bonar>plink -ssh admin@192.168.100.250 -pw password1 
Using username "admin". 
Access denied
admin@192.168.100.250's password:
```